# JSON.Net load a file, modifying it and re-saving it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm loading JSON.net to load a JSon file, then I need to find some "target/keywords" that I have to delete and finaly resaved it.

So, I need to load the file, find the keyword, delete the section related to this keyword and save the file back with this modification.

I use the very last version of JSON.Net.

Any idea ?

Here is my input :
1) file name
2) keyword, by example : dns_prefetching/host_referral_list

Some kind of files I try to modify are the google chrome files, like :
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State

Thanks

Comment: "I can parse a JSon file, but I'm not able to parse it" - can you or can you not parse it? You need to be more specific about your issue. Do you not know how to modify it? How exactly do you need to modify it? Can you give us a sample of the input and the expected output?

Comment: The usual process for this would be to: 1) Deserialize the json to an object 2) modify the object with the new value 3) Serialize back to json.

Comment: But I can't deserialize, I suppose ? Because I don't have the C# related objects ! On the other side I'm just looking to delete some "sections" in the json file. For this I have to find some keywords. Maybe there are soe easy way to do this !! Thanks

Comment: You can use [JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) to parse your json and then `Remove` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html). You can then index with the name of a property and you can use `Remove` to remove tokens. For example:

```
string json = @"{CPU: 'Intel',Drives: [    'DVD read/writer',    '500 gigabyte hard drive'  ]}";
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
var d = o["Drives"];
Console.WriteLine(d);    // outputs DVD read/writer and 500 gigabyte hard drive
d[0].Remove();
Console.WriteLine(d);    // outputs only 500 gigabyte hard drive
```

Comment: Thanks,

I have see JObject... but it seems it does not exists anymore !
I can use the serializer, the reader etc... but can't find JObject !!! Is it normal ?

Comment: @Spectral: It's in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace.